# How to set CommandItem to true again after printing data in radGrid Telerik UI for Asp.Net AJAX?

Tags: radgrid

I wanted disables the **Paging, Filtering Item and Command Item** to print all page .I have been put some code behind as follow:

```
foreach (GridItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(new GridItemType[] { GridItemType.Pager, GridItemType.FilteringItem, GridItemType.CommandItem }))
                item.Display = false;
```

However, How to set **Paging, Filtering Item and Command Item** to true again. If I close the window by clicking the "x" button the print window disappear and the page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a similar piece of code in the Page_Load or whatever initial code block you have available that sets them all back to display = true;

```
foreach (GridItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(new GridItemType[] { GridItemType.Pager, GridItemType.FilteringItem }))
                item.Display = true;
```

Comment: Thanks your reply, However your solutions has not working which I have been done it. Have you any another solutions?